# What Http Status code should be returned from WebAPI Delete action if a record cannot be deleted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

What Http Status code should be returned from a HttpDelete action if a record cannot be deleted from the database because of database integrity?

403 - Forbidden

405 - Method not allowed

409 - Conflict

??

Comment: Why does Stack Overflow keeping to get flooded with "which status code to use" questions? Can't you decide that for yourself? What did your research show?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245268/whats-the-right-http-status-code-for-a-response-when-i-cant-perform-a-delete-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view **HTTP code 409**.
RFC does not say anything about this concrete situation but also it is not rejecting it.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be
> completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource. This code is used in situations where the user might be able
> to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The server SHOULD
> generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to
> recognize the source of the conflict.

Source:
[REST HTTP status code if DELETE impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122472/rest-http-status-code-if-delete-impossible)

And why do I think that 403 and 405 are not appropiate?

- **403** - Forbidden. It's related with permissions.  But the scenario that you are describing occurs after authentication/authorization.
- **405** - Method not allowed. This is usually related with the "object" exposed by the endpoint, it accepts X number of verbs and the one you requested is not available.  Throwing this error in a determined situation like integrity-check would be confusing for the RESTful logic.